# How to find duplicates and list them separately using VBA in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

The answer "How to find duplicates and list them separately using VBA in Excel?" is exactly what I am looking for. I need help editing the language to fit my spreadsheet. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am not a programmer, just an enduser who admires the power of VBA. Thank you.

I've tried to edit the syntax but i cannot get it work in my spreadsheet.

```
Sub find_dups()

    ' Create and set variable for referencing workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Create and set variable for referencing worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Find current last rows
    ' For this example, the data is in column A and the duplicates are in column C
    Dim lngLastRowME As Long
    lngLastRowME = ws.Range("A29-7834-9-0003").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lngLastRowDups As Long
    lngLastRowDups = ws.Range("C29-7834-9-0003").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Create and set a variable for referencing data range
    Dim rngME As Range
    Set rngME = ws.Range("a4:a" & lngLastRowME)

    Dim lngRowCount As Long
    lngRowCount = 0

    Dim clME As Variant
    Dim lngCount As Long

    Dim lngRowIndexME As Long
    Dim lngRowIndexDups As Long
    lngRowIndexDups = lngLastRowDups + 1

    ' Variable to store those values we've already checked
    Dim strAlreadySearched As String


    For Each clME In rngME.Cells

        ' Reset variables
        lngCount = 0


        ' See if we've already searched this value
        If InStr(1, strAlreadySearched, "|" & clME.Value & "|") = 0 Then

            ' We haven't, so proceed to compare to each row
            For lngRowIndexME = 1 To lngLastRowME

                ' If we have a match, count it
                If rngME.Cells(lngRowIndexME, 1).Value = clME.Value Then
                    lngCount = lngCount + 1
                End If

            Next lngRowIndexME

            ' If more than 1 instance
            If lngCount > 1 Then
                ' Dup's were found, fill in values under duplicates
                ws.Cells(lngRowIndexDups, 3).Value = clME.Value
                ws.Cells(lngRowIndexDups, 4).Value = lngCount

                ' Drop down a row
                lngRowIndexDups = lngRowIndexDups + 1

                ' Capture this value so we don't search it again
                strAlreadySearched = strAlreadySearched & "|" & clME.Value & "|"


            End If
        End If

    Next clME



End Sub
```

runtime error 400

[Screen Shot and Workbook](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10V6ggQIjSqmZCnt2xpdSOywpiPFkjqxJ?usp=sharing)

Comment: is `A29-7834-9-0003` the name of a range, because it is not a viable address.

Comment: Scott thank you for replying so quickly. I can send you the workbook or a screen print so you can see what i am working with.

Comment: The lines for `lngLastRowME` and `lngLastRowDups` seem inappropriate, or at least not robust.  `.End(xlUp).Row` may move outside of the range if it is contiguous; what may be more appropriate for the last line is using `.Rows.Count` and adding those to the ranges row (if you use `Range("NAME").Row` you will get the first row of a named range, so you can say `lrDups = Range("Name").Row + Range("Name").Rows.Count - 1` for a final row reference.  The `-1` is because you are including in your count the first row

Comment: Cyril thanks for the reply. Like i said to Scott if you want a screen shot or the workbook, which is really small to see what i am working with.

Comment: @Orlando565 [edit] your post adding the screen shot, but realize that Range expects and address(ie `"A100"`) not a value in a cell.

Comment: It won't let me add a screen shot. Not enough reputations. :-(

Comment: You would save the image to imgur.com then paste the link in your question

Comment: Scott i placed a screenshot of my work and the workbook on my Google drive and shared it.